# Recursive length of largest ascending consecutive subarray (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I have an assignment in the university to write a recursive function in C++ that finds the length of the longest ascending consecutive sub array of an array or integers. In addition, I have a code skeleton that I must use for my code and the function must not contain loops & more function.

For example, for the array 1,2,4,6,4,21,21,22,0,1,3,5,100,7
The result will be 5 (because 0 to 100 are 5 numbers).

The skeleton is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

int get_max_series(int a[], int size);

int main() {
    int i, size_array, array[MAX_SIZE];
    scanf("%d", &size_array);
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    printf("%d", get_max_series(array, size_array));
    return 0;
}

int get_max_series(int a[], int size) {
    // My code should be here
}
```

I've succeeded to write a function that counts the number of ascending pairs, but failed in reseting the counter when the pair is descending. The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

int get_max_series(int a[], int size);

int main() {
    int i, size_array, array[MAX_SIZE];
    scanf("%d", &size_array);
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    printf("%d", get_max_series(array, size_array));
    return 0;
}

int get_max_series(int a[], int size) {
    if (size == 1)
        return 1;

    if (a[0] < a[1])
        return 1 + get_max_series(&a[1], size - 1);

    return get_max_series(&a[1], size - 1);
}
```

I'll be happy to get some advice how to get my code work for this scenario, or change the code entirely.
Thanks !

Comment: Hey Shahar! It's unclear what your question is here. Are you asking us why your current code isn't working and how you can fix it? In that case, please show us a [MCVE] of the code. Otherwise, please specify your question!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a code.service, nor a "do my assigment" one. A least, show your efforts so far and the issues you meet.

Comment: So it has to be a consecutive subarray, then?  If non-consecutive subsequences were allowed then for instance 1,2,4,6,21,22,100 would be longer.

Comment: There are two ways to approach the problem: 1) use global variables to hold information about the search, or 2) create a helper function that has more parameters. I suspect that you're supposed to use option 2, since global variables are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Code-Apprentice, I already know how to debug code :) thanks

Comment: user3386109, thanks for your reply, I've just edited the body - I must not use more functions :(. maybe the global/static variables will do the work, but its a bit ugly.

Comment: Daniel Schepler, thanks for your reply. It has to be consecutive. I've just edited the body of the question :)

Comment: Use a `static` counter inside `get_max_series()` which is updated only if it increases. So, you can avoid that `1` at `return 1 + ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use static/global variables, or a helper function, you can use the following reduction for an array of size > 1 (it will be slow, though, since it does two recursive calls):

If `a[0]>=a[1]` then we cannot have `a[0]` in the maximal ascending subarray since it violates our notion of ascendancy so we return get_max_series(a+1, size - 1) like you have on your code.

When `a[0]<a[1]` we have two cases:

If `get_max_series(a+1,size-1)==size-1`, then the whole subarray a[1],...,a[size-1] is ascending. This implies a[0],a[1],...,a[size-1] is also ascending so we can return `1 + get_max_series(&a[1], size-1)` in this case.

**HOWEVER** if `get_max_series(a+1,size-1)!=size-1` that means that the  subarray a[1],...,a[size-1] isn't ascending, so the maximal subarray cannot contain both a[1] and a[size-1] (by contiguity it would have to include everything in between, which would make it non-ascending).

Therefore, you return `max(1+get_max_series(&a[0], size-1), get_max_series(&a[1], size-1))`.
NOTE that here you do two calls to get_max_series, so your computational cost quickly grows(basically the same inefficiencies that appear when you do the naive recursive implementation of the fibonacci function).

The function would be something like

```cpp
int get_max_series(int a[], int size) {
    if (size <= 1)
        return size;
    int max_sub = get_max_series(&a[1], size - 1);
    if (a[0] >= a[1])
        return  max_sub;
        else{
            if (max_sub==(size-1))
                return size;
            else
                return std::max(get_max_series(&a[0], size-1), max_sub);
            }
}
```

I'm using `std::max` here, but if you don't want to use the `algorithm` library you can find the maximum of two numbers using if-else.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an O(n) routine that seems to follow your rules (the variable names should help explain what's going on):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

int get_max_series(int a[], int size);

int main() {
    int i, size_array, array[MAX_SIZE];
    scanf("%d", &size_array);
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    printf("%d", get_max_series(array, size_array));
    return 0;
}

int get_max_series(int a[], int size) {
    int i = size - 1;

    if (i < 2){
      if (a[1] > a[0])
        return a[0] = 2;
      else
        return a[0] = 1;
    }

    int max = get_max_series(a, i);
    int max_up_to_i = a[i - 2];

    if (a[i] > a[i - 1]){
      a[i - 1] = 1 + max_up_to_i;
      if (a[i - 1] > max)
        max = a[i - 1];

    } else {
      a[i - 1] = 1;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, storing additional information in the array itself. Very clever :)

Answer (score -1):

The longest ascending subarray does not necessarily start at the beginning of the array. Therefore,

```
    return 1 + get_max_series(&a[1], size - 1);
```

is incorrect. I don't see how you can salvage the approach relying on inspecting just one character, at least within a given signature. Consider finding the longest ascending sequence at the beginning of the array, then recursing into the rest, along the lines of:

```
    int get_max_series(int a[], int size)
    {
        int n = get_longest_acsending_prefix(a, size);
        if (n == size)
            return n;
        return max(n, get_longest_ascending_prefix(a + n, size - n));
    }
```

That said, I don't see a point of recursion here.